# Pushing changes in the git submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-push

I have a problem with pushing changes in submodule repo.

```
add submodule add https://github.com/ikalnytskyi/termcolor.git
git add .
git commit -m "Add the new color submodule"
```

After that I made some changes in the **termcolor** submodule

```
cd termcolor
echo Hello>>hello.txt
git add .
git commit -m "Add hello.txt"
```

**Finally**, I want to push this commit to my remote repo, but I think git wants login and password for this submodule repo, which, of course, I don't know.

```
git push origin master
Username for 'https://github.com': lyalival
Password for 'https://lyalival@github.com': 
remote: Invalid username or password.
```

**So, the question is, why git doesn't push it to my project repository?**

P.S. For instance, in my main folder, I push the changes without writing login and password, I just typing

```
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved it. I thought that git adds **local copy** in my repository, but it doesn't.

So, in case I want change the submodule, I need create a new project and then

```
cd submodule
git remote set-url origin [link_to_my_project]
```

And then I was able to

```
git push origin master
```